# TouchableHighlight react native button image is being displayed but its not getting clicked

Tags: javascript, css, react-native

I am trying to make image as button , due to the style settings my button is not getting clicked. I have added this coded into scrollView.
if I make it relative the position of button will be on at begining of screen and it works, but it is not working in absolute position

```css
loadbutton: {
  alignItems: 'center',
  position: 'absolute',
//  justifyContent: 'center',
  top: 1200,
//  bottom: 10,
//  left: width/6
//  borderRadius: 5,
},
```

```js
  <TouchableHighlight onPress={Actions.DrScreen}
      style={styles.loadbutton}
      >
        <Image
        
          resizeMode="cover"
          source={require("../../images/start.png")}
        />
      </TouchableHighlight>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => {Actions.DrScreen}}
      style={styles.loadbutton}
      >
        <Image

          resizeMode="cover"
          source={require("../../images/start.png")}
        />
      </TouchableHighlight>
```

Answer (score 0):

solved it by changing the marginTop instead of top

```css
loadbutton: {
//  alignItems: 'center',
  marginTop: 1200,
  paddingBottom: 30,
  //position: 'absolute',
  //justifyContent: 'center',
//  top: 100,
 //bottom: 100,
   left: width/6+2
//  borderRadius: 5,
},
```